# Short story / chart involving heart transplants between professions

Tags: story-identification

I read it in a paperback of short stories. It came from one of my father's books, so probably 60s.I think it was in a volume with Philip K. Dick's "The Electric Ant" and Larry Niven's "Death by Ecstasy". I don't remember if there was an introductory text, but most of it was a chart, over multiple pages where the heart of one profession was placed in the body of another with a short blurb of the result with the idea being that the heart carried desire and the body skills/talent. I remember poets, prostitutes, and engineers being among those so crossed, and I remember one of the outcomes, I think involving the heart of a poet, was "He committed suicide".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could this be "The Hospital of Transplanted Hearts", by D M Thomas?  According to [ISFDB](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?97609), it was in two different anthologies with "The Electric Ant" (though not anything by Niven).  And I found a quote on Google referring to it as one of a group of "clever graphic poems, more in the nature of grids or flow-charts".

edited to add: I found a better description [here](https://deathrobotsfrommars.wordpress.com/2014/10/20/the-years-best-science-fiction-3-brian-w-aldiss-ed-harry-harrison-ed-1970/):

> The poet has constructed a grid in which the heart of a certain category of patient on one axis can be read against the body of another category of person on another axis. Thus, one can look up the heart of a sadist in the body of a whore and find an apt or witty description inserted therein.

Comment: That looks to be out. Thank you!